# How to change X label with pandas groupby function?

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

```
%matplotlib inline
df['남자합'] = df[df.iloc[:,4:8]>=0.5].sum(axis=1)
df.groupby('지번').남자합.plot(figsize= (15,8))
```

'남자합' = Sum Male's row of each city
'지번' = The name of each city

i attached the result, x label shows just number. i wanna ask you to change x label, and what is the meaning of these numbers before changing?

[image: RESULT]

Answer (score 0):

you could do something like this

```
plt.xlabel('남자합', fontsize=18)
```

and simlarly for the y-axis:

```
plt.ylabel('ylabel', fontsize=16)
```

Comment: i mean, x label should be shown as a each of city. because i grouped city name. and y label (남자합) is now shown the rate what i wanted. but i dont know why xlabel is shown like this.

Answer (score 0):

You can do :

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax= plt.subplots()
plt.set(title:"Name of the city",xlabel="anything you want",ylabel="anything you want")
```

the above method is easy and can be used in matlplotlib

Answer (score 0):

```
df.groupby('지번').남자합.sum().plot(figsize = (15,8), kind = 'bar', facecolor= 'g', edgecolor='b')
```

I forgot Sum function of each city! solved.